# Stop user from canceling hibernation

Tags: windows-7, sleep, hibernate

I have my laptop set to warn me when the battery is at 25% and got to hybrid sleep at 15%.

Well, I must have been extremely focussed on what I was working on because I didn't see the warning bubbles and suddenly lost power and some amount of work.

Is there a way to force the system to go to hibernation/sleep regardless what I am doing or warn me in such a way so I cannot miss it, a system dialog box perhaps?

Thanks.

---

EDIT: I've looked at task scheduler and it does have the ability to trigger actions based on events but I don't think battery events get logged... :(

I already have a WScript for checking the battery status and level, I could have it continually running in the background I guess... I'd prefer a more elegant way though.

Comment: Do you have a laptop or a desktop?

Comment: @mpboom It is a laptop.